# Overwrite sharepoint css

Tags: css

I have a div into sharepoint layout with a class:

```
<div class="welcome-content">
```

by default it have:

```
margin: 5px 0 0;
```

I want to change to `margin: 5px 0 20px -100px;`

How can I achieve it, it can be with Script Editor and I need to rewrite class with `!important` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `!important` as the following

```
<style>
.welcome-content
{
 margin: 5px 0 20px -100px !important;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are a person who doesn't like !important (I like it, I don't like to fuss), you can try to get around SharePoint overriding your styles by calculating the specificity of your css - the higher weight 'wins'.
[Specificity Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

```
9. Calculating a selector's specificity

A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:

count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
ignore the universal selector
Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.

Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

Examples:

*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
Note: Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity.
```

Instead of using `.welcome-content` (weight 10), maybe you can add some more references to the front of that to increase the style weight.
`div.welcome-content` gives a weight of 11. Maybe find something further up the DOM that has an ID and use that.